# Cookies do not stored when set it with axios POST method

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I'm trying to *write* and *read* cookies and falling into a problem below.

This is my basic server side:

**server.js**

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

import routes from '...';
app.use("/foo", routes);

app.listen(8888);
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = express.Router();
routes.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("myFoo", "abcd");
    res.send("Cookie added");
    }
});

routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.cookies.myFoo);
    }
});
export default routes;
```

And my client side at "http://localhost:3000".

I do two HTTP request

```
POST http://localhost:8888/foo
GET http://localhost:8888/foo
```

And get the response exactly what I expected `abcd`. Also, the cookie exists in the browser tab Application > Cookies too.

The problem cases when `axios` is used in the client.

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8888/foo"
});

async function setCookie(object) {
    return api.post("/", object)
    .then((res) => {
        return res;
    });
}

function getCookie() {
    return api.get("/")
    .then((res) => {
        return res;
    });
}

setCookie({})
.then((res) => {
    getCookie();
})
```

The `api.post()` run usually and the header response `Set-Cookie` is correct. But cookies in the browser tab Application > Cookies are empty. Also, `api.get()` get the `undefined`.

I did try to move `res.cookie()` or the *set cookie job* in server side to GET route it WORKS on both `HTTP` and `axios`

```
routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("myFoo", "abcd");
});
```

tldr: Set cookie in HTTP POST method work fine but when client use `axios` to call so it causes problems.

Can you show me why this happened? And which code part went wrong that caused me into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are only used in cross-origin Ajax requests when:

- The client asks to use them
- The server grants permission to use them cross origin

So you need to change the client side code to ask for them:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8888/',
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

And the server code to grant permission (note that you can't use credentials at the same time as the wildcard for origins).

```
app.use(cors({ 
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', 
    credentials: true 
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine with your help. I have tried the `credentials` solution before and the problem is still there so I ignored it, your answer makes me realize I have done it wrong.

Comment: One more question, why is the `HTTP` request working? I look into the `HTTP` header and do not see any `credentials` config fields.

Comment: `credentials` doesn't change what is sent (besides the cookies). It makes the request preflighted and makes the browser look for `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the response.

Comment: This isnt't working for me...